# is it possible capture sending email status outlook add-in c#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I have **ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler** email sending event, but this event in email sending status is always false, so any event capture email sending is true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `MailItem.Sent` is still false? This is to be expected. The very first time you can access the sent message is when `Items.ItemAdd` event fires on the Sent Items folder. By then Sent property will be true and all the sender related properties will be populated.

Comment: sorry for late reply, but thanks your answer is very helpful for me.